# How to format plaintext in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to extract the content of a webpage in plain text - without the html tags. Here's some sample code:

```
$dom = \Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser::file_get_html($url);
$result['body'] = $dom->find('body', 0)->plaintext;
```

The problem is that what I get in $result['body'] is very messy. The HTML was removed, sure, but sentences often merge into others since there are no spaces or periods to delimit where the text from one HTML tag ended, and text from the following tag begins.

An example:

```
<body>
    <div class="H2">Header</div>
    <div class="P">this is a paragraph</div>
    <div class="P">this is another paragraph</div>
</body>
```

Results in:

"Headerthis is a paragraphthis is another paragraph"

Desired result:

"Header. this is a paragraph. this is another paragraph"

Is there any way to format the result from plaintext or perhaps apply extra manipulation on the innertext before using plaintext to achieve clear delimiters for sentences?

EDIT:

I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
foreach($dom->find('div') as $element) {
    $text = $element->plaintext;
    $result['body'] .= $text.'. ';
}
```

but there's a problem when the divs are nested, since it would add the content of the parent, which includes text from all children, and then add the content of the children, effectively duplicating the text. This can be fixed simply by checking if there is a `</div>` inside the `$text` though.

Perhaps I should try [callbacks](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. By removing HTML tags you're somehow removing formatting from the text, but you actually want some other sort of formatting which you need to define in a more precise manner. What kind of manipulation do you want to apply on the text? What is your desired output?

Comment: I've added an example for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like this? Tested.

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dom = \Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser::file_get_html("index.html");

$result['body'] = implode('. ', array_map(function($element) {
    return $element->plaintext;
}, $dom->find('div')));

echo $result['body'];
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="H2">Header</div>
    <div class="P">this is a paragraph</div>
    <div class="P">this is another paragraph</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Answers the original question, although there are some further nuances, like nested divs, that this won't handle well, but that wasn't a part of the original HTML example, so it can be considered out of scope.

Comment: For nested Divs, you can add to the array map a nested array_map and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$result = array();
foreach($html->find('div') as $e){
    $result[] = $e->plaintext;
}
```

Comment: it produces this: "Headerthis is a paragraphthis is another paragraph. "

Comment: U can get all div as array element

Comment: @cohaven I think that my updated code will be helpful for you